# Show different image on same Gridview Android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, imagefilter

I want to show different image in grid layout 
**MainActivity.java**

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isReadStorageAllowed()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GridActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("firstKeyName","FirstKeyValue");
intent.putExtra("secondKeyName","SecondKeyValue");
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

I want to show Images in GridLayout
my **GridActivity.java** code is as follows

```
Intent intent;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
intent = getIntent();
// Get the view from new_activity.xml
setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);


GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View v, int position, long id){
    }
});
```

And in ImageAdapter I want to get intend value of MainActivity to use it in filter in images(different image on single view using different button)

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        /*if (convertView == null) {*/
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350, 350));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        /*}
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }*/
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.b1, R.drawable.b2, R.drawable.b3,
            R.drawable.b4, R.drawable.b5, R.drawable.b6,
            R.drawable.b7, R.drawable.b8, R.drawable.b9,
            R.drawable.b10, R.drawable.b11, R.drawable.b12,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mThumbIds[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return mThumbIds[i];
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

    /*if (convertView == null) {*/
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350, 350));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    /*}
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }*/
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.b1, R.drawable.b2, R.drawable.b3,
            R.drawable.b4, R.drawable.b5, R.drawable.b6,
            R.drawable.b7, R.drawable.b8, R.drawable.b9,
            R.drawable.b10, R.drawable.b11, R.drawable.b12,
    };
}
```

Comment: how do I get Intent params of MainActivity.java in ImageAdapter.

Comment: Just define new field, then add constuctor or getter/setter method for it